# How to show custom field on specific custom post type posts only when filled

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, single, post-meta

On my demo website i would like to show some custom fields on posts of specific **custom post type**. And if possible only when they have a filled in value.
Demo site: http://www.jsfaber.nl/gibson-eb-2014-120th-anniversary/

What i have so far in single.php is:

```
<p>
Auteur: <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_author', true); ?><br>
Contributor: <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_contributor', true); ?><br>
</p>
```

but this is now shown on alle the posts in the website instead of only on guitar related posts.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the WP's [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). When a page is requested WordPress searches for the file to load in a specific order. You can create a [template specific to your custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates). You would copy the file called `single.php` and name the copy `single-{post_type}.php` where "post_type" is the name of your CPT. This file would then load instead of `single.php` every time a single custom post type page was requested.

As for only displaying the field, you could check if it has a value in an `if()` statement. When you validate the feild's value when the post is saved you can check if the user set anything, if they did not then you should set it to something falsy like an empty string.

Then the check in the template file would look something like this:

```
<?php
    $meta_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_author', true);
    $meta_contributor = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_contributor', true);
    if ($meta_author != '' && $meta_contributor != '') :
        echo '<p>
              Auteur: ' . $meta_author . '<br>
              Contributor: ' . $meta_contributor . '<br>
              </p>';
    endif;
    ?>

<!--Other template html-->
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. The specific template for the custom post type succeeded. With your If code both lines of meta tekst would not be shown if one value would not be filled, but with a little twist i got that to work too. Thanks!

Comment: '<?php
    $meta_author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_author', true);
    $meta_contributor = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'dublin_core_contributor', true);
    if ($meta_author != '') :
        echo '
              Auteur: ' . $meta_author . '<br>
       ';
    endif;
    if ($meta_contributor != '') :
        echo '
              Contributor: ' . $meta_contributor . '<br>
        ';
    endif;
    ?>'